# Neovim recognizes LaTeX class files (.cls) as filetype=st

Tags: neovim, filetype, filetype-tex

When I run `nvim test.cls` (a LaTeX class file looking something like this:

```tex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{landscapetest}[forcing landscape mode]

\LoadClass[landscape]{article}
\RequirePackage[landscape]{geometry}
```

), it does not recognize it as a TeX file, but instead as an `st` file (`:set filetype?` returns `filetype=st`). I'm aware that I can stick `% vim: set filetype=tex` at the top of the file, and that's what I'm doing now, but I'm wondering if there's a way for neovim to be smarter about it.

Ideally it would recognize these files as LaTeX files, but if I did edit an `st` file with nvim, it would recognize that correctly as well. Is this possible?

Comment: Looks like it will use `tex` if the first line starts with `%`. Maybe that could be expanded to `getline(1) =~ '^%' || getline(1) =~ '^\\'`? I don't know the exact syntax of TeX, Rexx, Visual Basic, and Smalltalk that all use the `.cls` extension. You can also set `g:filetype_cls` to override things.

Comment: Source: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/be807d5/runtime/autoload/dist/ft.vim#L142-L157 and https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/master/runtime/autoload/dist/ft.vim#L142-L157

Comment: https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/11380 – this should eventually make its way to Neovim too.

Comment: @MartinTournoij merged into both! thanks!